# How to limit size of Vim Syntastic location list window

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

Vim syntastic plugin pops up the errors and warnings location list and it needlessly consumes more screen space than needed for the list:

[image]

How can I configure syntastic to open a location list window that has only enough lines to show the list?

Comment: This is answered in the manual: `:h 'syntastic_loc_list_height'`, `:h syntastic-loclist-callback`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you [lcd047](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658042/lcd047) for pointing out the answer. I added the following to my vimrc and it worked:

```
" see :h syntastic-loclist-callback
function! SyntasticCheckHook(errors)
    if !empty(a:errors)
        let g:syntastic_loc_list_height = min([len(a:errors), 10])
    endif
endfunction
```